# How to get media codecs work for VLC

Tags: mediaplayer, codec

I have installed the media codecs for the media format support following opensuse-guide, and it gets Kaffeine player played the video format but didn't work for VLC, so my question is to deal with this issue.

For example when I play .flv with VLC:

```
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpgv". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpgv". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpgv". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpgv". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpgv". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpgv". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpgv". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "a52 ". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpga". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "mpgv". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
```

Answer (score 1):

**In the reply (below)** the symbol **//** needs to be preceded by **http:** (ie: **http://**)

On 04/09/2013 09:45 AM, **Ricardo Chung** wrote (in answer to a similar question in the opensuse forums - and I found this on //derkeiler.com/Mailing-L...sg00360.html):

*It looks you did not add the proper multimedia codecs from repositories.
You can open YaST ->Software Repositories->Add Packman Repositories and
installing the needed codecs or follow the directions on **//opensuse-guide.org/codecs.php***

and it works.

I would suggest following the directions on **//opensuse-guide.org/codecs.php**. I would NOT use the "one click" option (throws up lots of questions. I'm sure it's easy if you're very slick. I'm not), nor would I use the "manual codec installation" (it's OK but a bit laborious). I would, however, use "**codec installation in the terminal**":

Copy & paste the two lines:

**zypper addrepo -f //ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/packman...openSUSE_13.2/ packman**
**zypper addrepo -f //opensuse-guide.org/repo/13.2/ dvd**

These add the two repositories (packman & dvd) to YaST. Then, finally, copy & paste:

**zypper install libxine2-codecs k3b-codecs ffmpeg lame gstreamer-plugins-bad gstreamer-plugins-ugly gstreamer-plugins-ugly-orig-addon gstreamer-plugins-libav libdvdcss2**

The output will be about 350 lines. You will still be asked questions but the terminal stops running until the answer is given & the **1st** solution is always the one to choose (see below)

*Problem: libxine2-codecs-1.2.6-93.1.x86_64 requires libxine2 = 1.2.6, but this
requirement cannot be provided
uninstallable providers: libxine2-1.2.6-93.1.i586[Packman Repository]
libxine2-1.2.6-93.1.x86_64[Packman Repository]

libxine2-1.2.6-93.1.i586[packman]

libxine2-1.2.6-93.1.x86_64[packman]*
***Solution 1: Following actions will be done:

install libxine2-1.2.6-93.1.x86_64 (with vendor change)
openSUSE --> http://packman.links2linux.de

install libxine2-pulse-1.2.6-93.1.x86_64 (with vendor change)
openSUSE --> http://packman.links2linux.de***
*Solution 2: do not install libxine2-codecs-1.2.6-93.1.x86_64*
*Solution 3: do not install libxine2-codecs-1.2.6-93.1.x86_64*
*Solution 4: break libxine2-codecs-1.2.6-93.1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its
dependencies*
*Choose from above solutions by number or skip, retry or cancel [1/2/3/4/s/r/c]

..
(c): **1***
*Resolving dependencies...*
*Resolving package dependencies...*

Then you can play your Region 1 (or whatever) videos to your hearts content. Hope this is useful.

with thanks to **Ricardo Chung**

dmk

Comment: This, of course, is only good for SuSE - for anyone with a Debian based distro I would look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Answer (score -2):

You actually have to install VLC codecs seperately from the VLC repository for your distro

Comment: What's the name of the package(s)?